# ANTLR 4 out-of-heap for Java8 in Node JS

Tags: javascript, java-8, out-of-memory, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to parse Java 8 files and create an AST out of them using antlr 4, all in Javascript / Node JS. Everything seems to be going well, with the exception of the actual AST construction. When I call `parser.compilationUnit()` (which is the start rule in the Java8 antlr grammar it seems), the program does not terminate until it eventually runs out of heap.

Here is what I have done so far:

I managed to generate the Java8 antlr files using:

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript Java8.g4 -visitor`

I created the chars, lexer, tokens and parser following [this](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md) guide:

```js
const input = JavaExampleFile.code
const chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input)
const lexer = new Java8Lexer.Java8Lexer(chars)
const tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
const parser = new Java8Parser.Java8Parser(tokens)
parser.buildParseTrees = true
const tree = parser.compilationUnit()
```

Now the problem arises when I call `const tree = parser.compilationUnit()`. In the grammar, the compilationUnit is defined as the following:

```
compilationUnit
    :   packageDeclaration? importDeclaration* typeDeclaration* EOF
    ;
```

It seems that `typeDeclaration` is causing the issue. The interesting thing is that **everything works fine with Java but not with Java8.**

Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Any help would be appreciated.